# Visual Studio 2017 ClickOnce Prerequisites could not be found for bootstrapping

Tags: c#, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, clickonce

I am having an issue where a C++ project that my application references is not being loaded at runtime (i.e. I get an "file or assembly not found" exception).  After trying many different things I stumbled onto the click once prerequisites menu and noticed that there was a number of prerequisites with the yellow error sign beside them.

I am not sure if this will resolve my "assembly not found" exception or if I am going down the wrong path, but I figured I'd ask.  Why does Visual Studio not find these prerequisites on my machine??

I have searched in some folders like C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages but I don't think this folder contains my prerequisites (though I am not 100% sure what to be looking for in these folders), instead it contains to more folders called SqlClrTypes_x64 and SqlClrTypes_x86.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows 10 64 bit machine.

Does anybody have any ideas on why visual studio cannot find the prerequisites in the image below?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio 2017, all packages stored on  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages` path are only visible in prerequisites list.
In your case, those packages are added from machine which has those packages at above location.

You might have to create custom packages for above files, like given in the example below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/creating-bootstrapper-packages?view=vs-2017